# RequestMapping results in 404 - Spring Boot

Tags: spring, web-applications, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

I am a newbie to Spring Boot. In the following simple code when I am using @RequestMapping, http://localhost:8080/person results in the following error:

Error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@Controller
public class SpringBootAlphaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAlphaApplication.class, args);
    }


    @RequestMapping("/person")
    public String  addPerson(Model model){
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setName("SomeName");
        person.setAge(28);
        model.addAttribute("person", person);
        return "personview";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String testPath(){
        return "Test URL";
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you want to return? Do you want to return html or json?

Comment: @ksokol addPerson would be returning html, but the method testPath is supposed to return a simple String but the resources are not found. One thing to note is that it is returned if I use ResponseBody together with RequestMapping

Comment: What templating engine do you want to use? JSP, Freemarker, Velocity, Thymleaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your answer, then you should actually have gotten another error. If you're using **spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf**, the error you would get if your view can be resolved (but does not contain a `</meta>` tag), should be:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>".
```

And you should get a `type=Internal Server Error, status=500` status.

To solve that you can actually configure the strictness of Thymeleaf by setting its mode to `LEGACYHTML`:

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
```

However, it requires you to add another dependency called **nekohtml**:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
  <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.15</version>
</dependency>
```

The not found error usually means something else:

- Your view cannot be resolved: Maybe you misspelled the name of the HTML, or you didn't place it in the correct folder
- Your request mapping cannot be resolved: Maybe you misspelled the name, or you're using the wrong context path
- You don't have a template engine to resolve views

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by `<meta>` not having an ending tag `</meta>`. Apparently Thymleaf is very strict with tags, wish more meaningful messages were returned instead of a 404 Not Found.

Comment: It actually **does** give you more meaningful messages.